# Eclipse is saying "Update Android Developer Toolkit"

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ubuntu-12.04

I've somehow managed to mess up my Eclipse and Android set-up and I'm not sure how to fix it. The symptoms of the problem are as follows:

In Preferences > Android, I try to select the location of android-sdk-linux, when select the error appears "This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 20.0.0 or above.  Current version is 18.0.0.v201203301601-306762.  Please update ADT to the latest version."

Going to Help > Check for Updates in Eclipse, returns no updates found

Going to Help > Install new software and selecting work with ADT Plugin - https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/. Selecting Developer Tools and next, returns

Cannot complete the request.  See the error log for details.
"Android DDMS" will be ignored because it is already installed.
"Android Development Tools" will be ignored because it is already installed.
"Android Hierarchy Viewer" will be ignored because it is already installed.
"Android Traceview" will be ignored because it is already installed.
"Tracer for OpenGL ES" will be ignored because it is already installed.

If I then take a look at what is already install, Android Development Tools is listed and the version is 20.0.0.v201206242043-391819

Now for the interesting part:

If I go to Help > About > Installation Details > Features is lists Android Development Toolkit as Version: 20.0.0.v201206242043-391819 but if I then go into Plug-ins it lists Android Development Toolkit as Version: 18.0.0...

Sorry for yet another question on updating the ADT as there already seem to be quite a lot of questions on the topic but I've tried the typically solutions and they does seem to be getting me very far

Some extra info, that people often ask for
OS: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
Eclipse Platform: Version 3.7.2

Comment: Have you opened the SDK manager and verified you have the latest SDK version. If so, just remove the ADT plugin and re-install it.

Comment: Have you tried to close eclipse and open again. It happens to my that always suspend the computer and never close eclipse. I update the adt but when checking for updates It says that I have adt 19... hope to help :)

Comment: @Litus yeah and I've tried turning the computer off and on again :) always the first thing to try as it seems of solution a worryingly large number of issues

Comment: @tencent it says that I already have the lastest SDK version, removing the ADT and re-installing still didn't solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

In your installed folder of `eclipse` there is a folder named `plugins`.
Do the following:

1. Find the plugin file/folder of `Andriod` `SDK` and move it to some other folder for backup.
2. Download from `Android` site the latest version of `Android` `SDK`
3. Copy/paste it in your `plugins` folder
4. Restart `eclipse`

And everything should be fine.

Comment: I've located the plug in file in /usr/lib/eclipse/plugins and its called com.android.ide.eclipse.adt_18.0.0.v201203301601-306762.jar. From the andriod site (https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html) I downloaded ADT-20.0.0.zip, and found inside it a file called  com.android.ide.eclipse.adt_20.0.0.v201206242043-391819.jar. I then replace the old adt file with the new one and now all of the android plugin opinions have disappeared from eclipse

Comment: Try to unzip the downloaded file and put it as it is in the plugins folder. if that didn't do you need to download all the android plugs that eclipse needs and replace the old one with them, since the versions work with the same version, maybe some compatibility issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try using http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ instead of https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Comment: I've just tried this in Install new software but I'm getting the same error of Cannot complete the request.  See the error log for details.
"Android DDMS" will be ignored because it is already installed.
"Tracer for OpenGL ES" will be ignored because it is already installed.
"Android Traceview" will be ignored because it is already installed.
"Android Development Tools" will be ignored because it is already installed.
"Android Hierarchy Viewer" will be ignored because it is already installed.   thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2):

In the end, I just couldn't fix it so I complete uninstalled it and set it back up again from scratch, thanks for your help

Comment: yes get the latest eclipse and then you can set its workspace to where  your projects were before and then your old android devices just work follow the instructions installing the eclipse plugin https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html#Download

Answer (score 0):

Run software updates in Eclipse (Help > Check for Updates) and update the ADT.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the game on this one, but I figured I would contribute since I ran into the same problem myself.  In order to check for installed plugins in Eclipse, do the following.

From the Eclipse Preferences Menu..
-Select "Install/Update"
-From the General Menu, There should be a link button that says "Uninstall or Update"

This should take you to a prompt that will allow you to uninstall anything you've added onto your Eclipse setup!

Answer (score 0):

Go to the below site
https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html
and download ADT-22.3.0.zip from the site.
then follow the procedures mentioned there..

Answer (score 0):

uncheck "Contact all update sites during install to find required software"

see: [Can not install Android ADT 21.1 on eclipse Juno (Windows 7) after upadate to SDK 21.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14866656/can-not-install-android-adt-21-1-on-eclipse-juno-windows-7-after-upadate-to-sd)

Answer (score 0):

After updating the Android SDK Tools to the latest version from the SDK manager, do the following:

1. Go to Eclipse->Help->Install new software
2. Type https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ in the "Work with" Text box
3. From the list, select all and then click next
4. Now Eclipse will prompt you that in order to install these new software, Eclipse will uninstall the old version (in this case Android Developer Tools), click on next, read and accept the license and wait for it to download
5. Restart Eclipse and everything should be working fine.