# Can not install Android ADT 21.1 on eclipse Juno (Windows 7) after upadate to SDK 21.1

Tags: android, adt

I have download ADT 21.1, and tried install it on eclipse
[image]

I got those:

The operation cannot be completed.  See the details.

Details:

Cannot complete the request.  See the error log for details.

Tracer for OpenGL ES will be ignored because it is already installed, and updates are not permitted.

Android DDMS will be ignored because it is already installed, and updates are not permitted.

Android Development Tools will be ignored because it is already installed, and updates are not permitted.

Android Traceview will be ignored because it is already installed, and updates are not permitted.

Android Hierarchy Viewer will be ignored because it is already installed, and updates are not permitted.

[image]

When I reopen SDK Manager, I still got this:
[image]

In Windows->Preference->Android, I got this:
[image]

Thus, I wanna reintall ADT, but I found I can't uninstall any Plug In, Uninstall.. button is gray!
[image]

Comment: Finally! I got answer! The problem is the Windows User is not administrator. After **running Eclipse as administrator**, at the beginning eclipse will update something. Than, everything is fine!

Comment: I tried running as administrator and I still got the same error:

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=profile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt,21.1.0.v201302060044-569685
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package,21.1.0.v201302060044-569685
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.base,21.1.0.v201302060044-569685

There are a few dozen more "no repository".

Comment: @Pmoney see my answer. I had this just now.

Answer (score 91):

In Eclipse, try:

Help > Install New Software

Then Choose the name you gave for https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ (working link)

Select the updates to install and then crucially, uncheck "Contact all update sites during install to find required software".

[image]

Comment: Had the same problem on my mac but your answer solved it, thanks.

Comment: As Eclipse is java based, and built for multiple platforms, this type of problem shouldn't be OS specific.

Comment: @ing0 Thanks for the "crucial" part, I was already downloading the entire package when I got it to work using your suggestion.

Comment: No problem. No idea why that's required, it must be a broken package or something.

Comment: YES.  "CRUCIAL" is the key word.  I just ran into the same problem, this solved it.  I hope this little notation gets back to the Android Developer site installation notes.

Answer (score 1):

I also confirm that this works (already mentioned by ing0)

In Eclipse (ADT)

> Help -->  Install New Software --->  Work with -->  Android Developer
>   Tools Update Site - http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Select all of the updates you want to install and UNCHECK option "Contact all update sites during install to find required software". After that everything should install as it is mentioned to be.