# Fixing Eclipse after ADT breaks

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, adt

SDK Manager told me I had updates and updated me from version 21 to 22, then said I should check for updates. I'm running bundled eclipse/ADT from about last month, Juno version 4.2.1

In Eclipse when it started it confirmed this and said ADT was out of date and I should update. Running update said no new updates.

so I then tried to 'Install new software' and select http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/, then pick the tools. I get the following error after confirming I wish to perform an update as I already have it installed.

Thanks. Why does Eclipse fall over every time a plugin installation/update is involved (well, it does for me :( )

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=profile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt,22.0.0.v201305140200--675183
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package,22.0.0.v201305140200--675183
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.base,22.0.0.v201305140200--675183
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms,22.0.0.v201305140200--675183
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger,22.0.0.v201305140200--675183
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer,22.0.0.v201305140200--675183
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview,22.0.0.v201305140200--675183
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay,22.0.0.v201305140200--675183
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt,22.0.0.v201305140200--675183
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms,22.0.0.v201305140200--675183
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger,22.0.0.v201305140200--675183
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer,22.0.0.v201305140200--675183
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview,22.0.0.v201305140200--675183
```

Comment: Manually download the ZIP file and use that instead, as described here: https://web.archive.org/web/20130513162212/http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html#Troubleshooting

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't update Eclipse ADT to 22](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585315/cant-update-eclipse-adt-to-22)

Comment: Related: [Can not install Android ADT 21.1 on eclipse Juno (Windows 7) after upadate to SDK 21.1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14866656/208273)

Answer (score 4):

Just change location address from http:// to https://

Go To Eclipse menu Window -> Preferences then Install/Update -> Available Software sites, select "Android Developer Tools Update Site" and click "Edit"

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and spent *hours* trying the solutions above and those listed in https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60149. Nothing worked for me.

Finally, I reinstalled the eclipse plugin (Help->Install New Software-Add, and then use https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/). This was simple and it worked. I think this was all due to a bug in eclipse that this new plugin version fixed.

(More details here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html)