# (Eclipse SDK update error) An error occur while collecting items to be installed

Tags: eclipse, sdk, updates

I just updated ADK and I encountered exactly the same problem (the same version of upgrade) as this guy ([Cannot update ADT from 22.3.0. to 22.6.1, no updates were found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22525178/cannot-update-adt-from-22-3-0-to-22-6-1-no-updates-were-found))

I followed their comments, yet I did not see the dialog mentioned in step 4 (4. You should see a dialog that says "this software is already installed, an update will be performed instead". Clicking ok will lead to 22.6.1 being installed.)

Instead, I have the error message that titled

> Problem occurred

It says

> Installing Software has encountered a problem. An error occurred while
>   collecting items to be installed

And a chunk of details is followed, which I do not understand (See below). Could someone help? Thx so much

> An error occurred while collecting items to be installed session
>   context was:(profile=profile,
>   phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=,
>   action=). No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt,22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package,22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.base,22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms,22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger,22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer,22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview,22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay,22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt,22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms,22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger,22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer,22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview,22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508

Comment: Have you tried the method stated in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14896322/621481

Comment: the problem is solved already ,thx. I re-installed the whole bundle finally.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As per jonesw's link  https://stackoverflow.com/a/14896322/621481  all you need to do is make sure you have unchecked 'Contact all update sites during install to find required software' from the eclipse install software screen.

Comment: the problem is solved already ,thx. I re-installed the whole bundle finally.

Comment: @ChrisNoldus Does this have any side effect?

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

I recently had a problem very similar to this.  And the answer from @ChrisNoldus did not work for me.  However I did find [this link](http://www.digitalsanctuary.com/tech-blog/general/no-repository-found-containing-error-when-update-eclipse.html):

Basically, there seems to be a problem when an available update site doesn't have a trailing '/' in its link.

I did not need to export anything to a file, but simply changed the configurations in Window->Preferences->Install/Update->Available Software Sites

Comment: What did you do there?

Comment: @Line: I went through the list of available sites and edited them, making sure they had a trailing '/'.  Keep in mind that this advice may be outdated.  I am currently on Oxygen, and my available sites seem to have a mixed bag of urls with and without trailing '/', and I am having no problems.  So maybe this is not an issue anymore.

Comment: This definitely is a server problem where the server doesn't return the content of the directory when there is no trailing slash, it simply takes the URL as something pointing to a file. -- Anyway, I just did what you said and the update finally went through, my list of software sites got refreshed and contains entries again without trailing slash. One still may argue why Eclipse doesn't add the slash itself...

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered the same problem and marked answer didn't worked for me. I had tried all the possible solutions to fix this error. Finally I found there were 2 workspace of eclipse under `C:\Users\Public\Documents` ( `Neon`, `Mars`). Just delete the folder which you don't want (Suppose you are working on Neon then delete the other folder `Mars`) and then try installing update.