# Cannot ReInstall TestNg after uninstalling it

Tags: eclipse, selenium, testng, testng-eclipse

[image]

I uninstalled TestNG from my eclipse and then i tried installing it again in this mentioned steps

> Help>Install new software>Selecting TestNG Checkbox>Clicking Next and
>   Finish buttons.

Then its showing the Error.

[image]

Comment: restart your eclipse and try again'

Comment: Restarted and tried to install again but it still shows me same error.Pls help me out with this issue

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23201685/eclipse-sdk-update-error-an-error-occur-while-collecting-items-to-be-installed

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20630446/installing-software-has-encountered-a-prob-android

Comment: As mentioned in the links i tried unchecking the "Contact all update sites during install to find required software" but still its showing me the error.Previously before un installing TestNG It was working well with no issues but after uninstalling it i am unable to install with the above mentioned steps..

Comment: Have you tried to download from marketplace

Comment: Yes,I tried it and It did not work Any thing i can do for resolving this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope good to clean the eclipse once and try to install again.

To start eclipse with clean, Edit the eclipse.ini file located in your Eclipse install directory and insert -clean as the first line. Further more info on it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030064/how-to-run-eclipse-in-clean-mode-and-what-happens-if-we-do-so)

Note: If you keep clean option, then eclipse always start deleting cache etc so it may take some time.

Then install TestNG from Marketplace( as already tried another ways)

Thank You,
Murali

Comment: As suggested i cleaned the eclipse  and tried Then to install TestNG from Marketplace but it shows me " Cannot complete the provisioning operation.  Please change your selection and try again. See below for details." .I tried many times but getting same result also when i tried  Help>Install new software>add new repository "http://beust.com/eclipse" its not showing TestNG checkbox it is showing "There are no items available in the list.

Comment: do one thing just right click on package and see wether testng option is there or not, mostly it is at bottom of that right context menu. if it is there then testng is present in eclipse.

Comment: Did it but cannot see TestNG option

Comment: ok, then testng is not present in eclipse. finally one is eclipse is updated one? on googling its may be reason because of old versions of eclipse..

Comment: Eclipse version i am using : 4.5.2.20160218-0600.I see its a updated version

Comment: try this instead of new testng version http://beust.com/eclipse-old/eclipse_6.9.10

Comment: Tried it with "http://beust.com/eclipse-old/eclipse_6.9.10" but its showing "Could not find http://beust.com/eclipse-old/eclipse_6.9.10".Do we have to correct the URL?Please let me know

Comment: One thing i am observing in my existing projects that still i am able to see test output folder even after uninstalling TestNG.May be is it the reason i am unable to install it again?

Comment: can try once checking other check boxes in testng installation screen you attached at first except show only software applicable to targer env, in my eclipse its like that only. it may helps you

Comment: also check that you have write access to eclipse folder and also have network access to that site, generally VPNs or firewalls blocks in offices.

Comment: Finally issue got resolved when i Use "http://testng.org/eclipse-beta" this url in testng installation screen.Now i am able to run the scripts and generate the results through testNG.Thanks a lot Murali.