# Eclipse Juno, neverending Android toolkit update

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

I haven't done any Android development for a while. During this while I updated my Galaxy Nexus (the first version) to Android 4.2.2. Yesterday I wanted to work on my game and I connected my mobile. I wrote some code, clicked run and the device appeared in the device selector, but instead of the familiar "Samsung Galaxy Something" I got some seemingly random number (it was probably a serial code for something) and the device was marked as offline, and it was not selectable for deploy and debug. Interestingly, the device itself was enabled for USB debug, the little monster was clearly visible in the upper left corner of the screen and everything seemed fine.

I tried to switch USB debug off and on again, with no success.

I tried to kill and restore the ADB server.

I tried to change the USB cable; I learned that there are **A** and **B** cables and in some cases it may be important to use the right one (I left the Samsung cable in another continent).

I tried to update the Android SDK with the Android update manager; after doing this the device when connected would prompt me to accept USB debug requests, so after all something has changed in a way. However, the device name still would not show up in the device manager and the status was still offline. Then, Eclipse started complaining that with the new SDK the Android Development Toolkit should be updated to version 21.

I ran the Eclipse update manager and it is still hanging at "Contacting Software Sites" at 50% after several hours.

I tried to add **-Declipse.p2.mirrors=false** at the end of **eclipse.ini**, but it doesn't seem to be faster.

I'm especially aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11505441/eclipse-is-saying-update-android-developer-toolkit) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15073165/android-4-2-2-adb-offline-even-after-sdk-upgrade), and nothing of what they said there helped.

**Edit**

Still at 50%, after one hour. I'll also try some of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804430/how-to-run-android-app-in-debug-mode-on-samsung-galaxy-y-s5360/8804473#8804473) at some point.

**Edit**

Cool, it finally started downloading the updates and after a while it crashed.

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt,21.1.0.v201302060044-569685
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.base,21.1.0.v201302060044-569685
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms,21.1.0.v201302060044-569685
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger,21.1.0.v201302060044-569685
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer,21.1.0.v201302060044-569685
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview,21.1.0.v201302060044-569685
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay,21.1.0.v201302060044-569685
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt,21.1.0.v201302060044-569685
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package,21.1.0.v201302060044-569685
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms,21.1.0.v201302060044-569685
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger,21.1.0.v201302060044-569685
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer,21.1.0.v201302060044-569685
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview,21.1.0.v201302060044-569685
```

Comment: I'm home, and never had this kind of proxy problems before. I don't have any HTTP software running on my laptop beside the browser. The router never misbehaved. However you made me think that there may be something wrong at a lower level: could it be that Eclipse uses TCP ports in some creative way? Like FTP active mode? No, right?

Comment: I am not sure about TCP ports. Just that I encountered similar problem before in my company. Anyway, have you tried using [mobile version of eclipse?](http://eclipse.org/mobile/), it seems to have less problem.

Comment: It is often a proxy problem, I read other accounts that fall in that case, which doesn't seem to be mine. However I'll double check my system configuration, maybe I installed some HTTP debug tool and I forgot about that, or it was automatically installed at some point. Thank you for sharing the info and the link to the mobile version of Eclipse, I may give it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also faced the same problem when i updated my sdk took kit and tried to update ADT , For downloading ADT 21.1 you need Helios 3.62 version or Higher I guess .

The best way is to download the Desire update using zip and then update using that zip file.
I saved my day using this method only. Remove the internet connection while updating using local zip file

This might Help :)

Comment: I ended up updating my development platform to the ADT Bundle (http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/bundle.html), which includes everything you need for Android development in a single package. I'm not 100% sure that you did the same, but your answer put me on the right track, thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like proxy issue. To deal with it, run SDK Manager.exe from the location of installed android-sdk. When SDK Manager is running, go to "Tools" --> "Options". Either of following two steps may help.

1. Insert proxy setting details if you are using proxy server  OR
2. Check the option for "Force https://... sources to be fetched using http://..."

Hope it will help in downloading all repository files.